# How to remove firestore listener while using a tab view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I have a controller named MessagesController that is a part of a tab bar controller. MessagesController constantly listens to realtime data from firestore. Since a controller in tab bar never gets killed (unless user kills the app), I was wondering what is the efficient way of using a listener?

Does deinit get called when app enters background? Should I use appWillResign notification to remove the listener?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Register for the applicationWillResignActive anywhere in your app.
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.applicationWillResignActive(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillResignActive, object: app)
}

@objc func applicationWillResignActive(notification: NSNotification) {
    listener.remove()
}
```

Or should I just leave it without removing it? Does this impact battery? It is just one listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Firestore documentation says, when you're no longer interested in listening to your data, detach the listener. If your app isn't configured to perform in the background or you don't want it to, you shouldn't be listening to data and updating the UI. Also consider that an app is more likely to be killed by the OS if it's performing work in the background versus an app that isn't. And economically, you're wasting money by paying for reads that will never be seen by anyone. When you re-enter the foreground and reattach the listener, it will fire immediately with fresh data (cached first and then uncached, which you can filter).

The simplest way to handle an app entering and exiting the background from within a view controller is the following notification pair:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appDidEnterBackgroundHandler(_:)), name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appWillEnterForegroundHandler(_:)), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
```

And if you ever want to know when an object is deinitialized (and not just view controllers), you can print from its deinit method:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {

    deinit {
        print("deinit")
    }

}
```

This will tell you if the view controller is being deinitialized. If the view controller is the root of the tab (and this is the main tab bar of the app), then it will never deinit. But if it's not the tab's root view controller—it was pushed to by a navigation controller within the tab, for example—then it will deinit when it's popped.

Comment: Yes this is a great and neat summary of the pieces of information I read in multiple articles. Unfortunately, my view controller is one of the roots of the tab bar. So I guess I have to use foreground and background notification.